# Code not running after AJAX Call Completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The first event listener works fine. When the second event listener runs, I can see the POST in Firebug and the return, but the `alert('test')` never happens.

```
$('.walkthrough').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).data('story');
    var num = $(this).data('revert');
    $('#tableauViz').replaceWith('<div id="tableauViz"></div>')
    $.post('',{method: 'getTicket', url: url},function(data){
        switchToStory(url,data);
        $('#help').html('<p>You are currently viewing the walkthrough, click here to <a href="#" data-num="'+num+'" class="exitWalkthrough">go back</a>.</p>');
    });
});
$('#addViz').click(function(){
    var url = $('#Viz-URL').val();
    var name = $('#Viz-Name').val();
    var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);
    if(url.match(regex) && name != ''){
        url = url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','');
        console.log(url);
        $.post('',{
            user_key:'5',
            method: 'addViz',
            url:url,
            name:name
        },function(data){
            alert('test');
        },'json');
    } else {
        alert("Please enter a valid URL and Name");
    }
});
```

Does anyone see anything in there that would be preventing this? How can i further debug this problem?

Comment: that callback is a *success* callback. If success isn't happening, error must instead be happening. Add an error callback to see the reason it failed. `},'json').fail(function (xhr, status, reason) { console.log(status, reason);})`

Comment: Shouldn't it show as error in Firebug?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Not unless it's an http error.

Comment: Now knowing that it isn't an http error, it's probably safe to assume the `reason` will be "parseerror" which simply means the json response is not valid json.

Comment: Wow, why the hell would I get down voted for this? And you are correct. Parse error as the response was blank though. I mean I'm in the middle of developing this which is why it's blank, I just didn't know empty would be a failure.

Comment: A blank string isn't valid json. Try it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I don't see how this question could help any future visitors, so i find it to be "not useful" hence the downvote. Don't take it personally.

Comment: That's fine I just don't see "questions that help future visitors" as a criteria listed in the site for the types of questions to ask, but to each their own. I tried to form the question title as something someone else might search for so while the X's and O's might be different the concept remains the same. Regardless thanks for your help.

Comment: @Leeish I edited your question, hopefully that'l be a bit more clear. Now the question is more focused on debugging ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing ajax requests, it's always a good idea to provide an error callback even if you don't think it will ever be called. Without one, you have no way of diagnosing a problem that isn't network related.

All jQuery ajax methods (other than .load) return a jQuery promise object that has done, fail, and always methods. Use the fail method to catch any failures.

```
$.post(url, data, successHandler).fail(function (xhr, status, reason) {
    console.log(
        xhr, // this is an object, it will contain the response text, headers, etc
        status, // the http status of the response, 20x or 30x for success
        reason // this is the reason that the response failed
    );
});
```

In your case, it failed because an empty string is not valid json.

Answer (score -2):

You need to delete first empty arg '' from your .post, othervise the url will get overwritten with an empty string.:

```
$.post({
    user_key:'5',
    method: 'addViz',
    url:url,
    name:name
},function(data){
    alert('test');
},'json');
```

Comment: I got that, but in any case if your first argiment i $.post is an empty string, it will override the url param and you will be sending data to ''.

Comment: False. It sends it to itself. I'm literally doing it now and it's working fine.

Comment: @Byaxy what he is doing is similar to `<a href="">reload</a>`, which is an anchor tag that goes to the current page.

Comment: Leesh and Kevin, thankyou for pointing these out, you are absolutly right. How ever having an empty string as a first argument in .$post will brake stuff...

Comment: I simply don't understand how you can say that as it's currently working fine.